# User friendly urls in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, user-friendly, joomla-sef-urls

I am working Joomla 1.5 . I am unaware of how to set user-friendly Urls to the site in Joomla1.5.

Give suggestions for keeping User-Friendly urls ...

I have changed the configuration for SEO as yes to apache mod_rewrite and Search engine friendly Urls .It changes the url as

http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/publicationsform but it shows me a 404 error and it works only when i put 
http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/index.php/publicationsform

how to resolve this .
Also even when i put http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/index.php/publicationsform my css is not getting added..

Answer (score 0):

You must have Apache mod-rewrite plugin enabled.
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_check_if_mod_rewrite_is_enabled_on_your_server